# Habilitar acentos en búsqueda Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un Input multiselect de la libreria [David Stutz](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/)

He añadido los siguientes parámetros, uno de los cuales es `enablaCaseInsensitiveFiltering` es `true` para que no haya problemas con las mayus, pero no funciona para los acentos

```js
    $('.multiselect').multiselect({
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
    $('.multiselectBasic').multiselect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando me tope con este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39867425) y explican que hay un parámetro que hay que colocar para que los acentos estén considerados en la búsqueda y se llama ***liveSearchNormalize***, por lo que el siguiente código te debería funcionar

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    liveSearchNormalize: false,
    enableFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});
$('.multiselectBasic').multiselect();
```

El atributo ***liveSearchNormalize*** lo puedes ver en la [documentación](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/) y dice:

> Setting liveSearchNormalize to true allows for accent-insensitive
>   searching.

Prueba con ese atributo para ver si te funciona, pienso que si ya que este plugin es una instancia del input select de bootstrap